# Clustering similar tweets in a corpus

Tags: python, sorting, hash-map, clustering, natural-language-processing

I am attempting to write a statistical program using an LDA model I've trained/created using Gensim. I am very new to Python and am a student level programmer. This current program is working and getting the results I want. In `get_similarities` I am comparing each of the user's document vector to all other user's in the community/clique. Currently it is a nested for and, after doing some searching online, others on this site have said to avoid doing this with dictionaries because of their unordered nature. I was hoping, with this post, to receive some input on things I'm doing wrong and possible Pythonic ways to enhance the operability of the program.

```
import bz2
import numpy as np
import scipy
import textblob
import gensim
import logging
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint
import os
from os import path
from gensim import corpora, models, similarities   

# load the wiki corpus
corpus = corpora.MmCorpus('data/wiki_corpus.mm')

# load the tfidf model
'''tfidf = models.TfidfModel.load('data/wiki.tfidf_model')'''

# load wiki dictionary
'''dictionary = corpora.Dictionary.load_from_text(bz2.BZ2File('data/wiki_wordids.txt.bz2'))'''
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary.load_from_text('data/wiki_dict.txt')

# load trained wiki model from file
lda_model = models.LdaModel.load('data/lda.model')

# create a directory for the user topics
if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname("user_topics/")):
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname("user_topics/"), 0o755)

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

# preprocess user tweets, --future-- preprocess tweet files(hashtags, @, RT, http...etc)
def tokenize(document):
    dict_array = []
    for word in document.lower().split():
        dict_array.append(word)
    return dict_array

# create a list of lines from tweet input file
def create_document(tweet):
    document = ""
    with open(tweet, 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            document += (str(line.rstrip('\n')) + " ")
        return document

def find_topics(tweetpath, filename, folder, i, user_doc_vec, corpus_list):
    document = create_document(tweetpath)

    # create dictionary for each user and save 
    user_dict = corpora.Dictionary([tokenize(document)])
    user_dict.save("./user_topics/clique" + str(i) + "/data/" + filename + ".dict")

    # create bag of words from input document
    # doc_bow = dictionary.doc2bow(document.lower().split())
    doc_bow = dictionary.doc2bow(gensim.utils.lemmatize(document))

    # append vectorized documents to list for creation of community corpus
    corpus_list.append(doc_bow)

    # queries the document against the LDA model and associates the data with probabalistic topics
    '''doc_lda = model[tfidf[doc_bow]]'''
    doc_lda = lda_model[doc_bow]

    # build map of user document vectors <k, v>(user_id, vec)
    user_doc_vec[filename] = doc_lda

    # get the topic id and distribution for each user 
    with open("./user_topics/topic_distribution", 'a') as outfile:
        outfile.write(filename)
        outfile.write(str(lda_model.get_document_topics(doc_bow)) + '\n')
'''
    # print the human-readable topics to file 
    with open("./user_topics/clique" + str(i) + "/" + filename, 'w') as outfile:
        for topic_id, dist in doc_lda:
            outfile.write(str(lda_model.show_topic(topic_id, topn=10)) + "\n")
'''
# for each user document vector compare how similar it is to every other user document vector
# using two metrics for measuring similarity. Dictionary <k, v>(user_id, doc_vec)
def get_similarities(user_doc_vec, i, filename):
    with open("./user_topics/cosine_similarities_clique" + str(i), 'a') as cosfile, open("./user_topics/hellinger_similarities_clique" + str(i), 'a') as helfile:
        for key in sorted(user_doc_vec):
            user = key
            vec_lda = user_doc_vec[key]
            dense_1 = gensim.matutils.sparse2full(vec_lda, lda_model.num_topics)
            del user_doc_vec[key]
            for key_2 in sorted(user_doc_vec):
                dense_2 = gensim.matutils.sparse2full(user_doc_vec[key_2], lda_model.num_topics)
                hel_sim = np.sqrt(0.5 * ((np.sqrt(dense_1) - np.sqrt(dense_2))**2).sum())
                cosfile.write(str(user) + '\t' + str(gensim.matutils.cossim(vec_lda, user_doc_vec[key_2])) + '\t' + str(key_2) + '\n')
                helfile.write(str(user) + '\t' + str(hel_sim) + '\t' + str(key_2) + '\n')


def main():
    # setup directories/working folders
    cliqueFolders = []
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk("./tweets"):
        for clique in dirs:
            if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname("./user_topics/" + str(clique) + "/")):
                os.makedirs(os.path.dirname("./user_topics/" + str(clique) + "/"), 0o755)
            if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname("./user_topics/" + str(clique) + "/data/")):
                os.makedirs(os.path.dirname("./user_topics/" + str(clique) + "/data/"), 0o755)
            cliqueFolders.insert(0, str(path) + "/" + str(clique) + "/")

    # for each clique, create and save dictionaries for each user's complete tweets,
    # compile and save a corpus of user tweet documents for each clique
    for i, folder in enumerate(cliqueFolders):
        corpus_list = []
        user_doc_vec = {} 
        for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        # for each tweet file create a document
            tweetpath = os.path.join(folder, filename)
            print(filename)
            find_topics(tweetpath, filename, folder, i, user_doc_vec, corpus_list)
        # save each community corpus
        corpora.MmCorpus.serialize("./user_topics/clique" + str(i) + "/data/corpus.mm", corpus_list)
        # output the user similarities to file
        get_similarities(user_doc_vec, i, filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hello! Please don't make changes to the original post once it has been reviewed, as that invalidates the current answers. Please see our meta side on [performing iterative reviews](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765) for more information!

Comment: Kenneth, if the copyright holder has requested this code to be removed, then the question should be deleted. Without the code, the question and answers aren't really useful for others.

Comment: I wrote all of this code. I got many examples from the Gensim tutorials but the code is my own. The reason I wanted to delete it was because we were going to use it for our research. I just realized though, that this is the older code and it's not being used for our current project so I will just leave it up here. Regardless, the below answer turned out to be a 'battle of who could care less' more than it was useful feedback.

Answer (score 3):

1. This is the same as just `return document.lower().split()`:

   ```
   def tokenize(document):
       dict_array = []
       for word in document.lower().split():
           dict_array.append(word)
       return dict_array
   ```
2. `logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)` -- this should be at the very beginning.
3. You have some business logic at the global level, like `lda_model = models.LdaModel.load('data/lda.model')` -- put it inside `main` so this module becomes modular and importable.
4. `cosfile.write(str(user) + '\t' + str(gensim.matutils.cossim(vec_lda, user_doc_vec[key_2])) + '\t' + str(key_2) + '\n')` -- use `format`:

   ```
   cosfile.write('{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(user, gensim.matutils.cossim(vec_lda, user_doc_vec[key_2]), key_2))
   ```
5. `'''doc_lda = model[tfidf[doc_bow]]'''` -- remove commented out code. Especially if you post code for review.
6. This

   ```
   def create_document(tweet):
       document = ""
       with open(tweet, 'r') as infile:
           for line in infile:
               document += (str(line.rstrip('\n')) + " ")
           return document
   ```

   could be simplified (and is faster) to:

   ```
   def create_document(tweet):
       with open(tweet, 'r') as infile:
           return ' '.join(line.rstrip('\n') for line in infile)
   ```
7. PEP-8.

   ```
   # for each user document vector compare how similar it is to every other user document vector
   # using two metrics for measuring similarity. Dictionary <k, v>(user_id, doc_vec)
   def get_similarities(user_doc_vec, i, filename):
   ```

   Put the comments inside a docstring. Describe what is the purpose of the function, not just what is the implementation. Describe the arguments and the returned value(s).
8. Refactor:

   ```
   for clique in dirs:
       if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname("./user_topics/" + str(clique) + "/")):
           os.makedirs(os.path.dirname("./user_topics/" + str(clique) + "/"), 0o755)
       if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname("./user_topics/" + str(clique) + "/data/")):
           os.makedirs(os.path.dirname("./user_topics/" + str(clique) + "/data/"), 0o755)
       cliqueFolders.insert(0, str(path) + "/" + str(clique) + "/")
   ```

   There is repeating code. Put `os.path.dirname("./user_topics/" + str(clique)` into a variable. Create a helper function which creates the directory if it doesn't exist. Use `str.format` instead of concatenating the strings.
9. `print(filename)` -- create a logger at the beginning of the file (`logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` and use it to log needed values (`log.debug('Filename: %s', filename)`). Using the logging framework and having a logging configuration will allow you to easily plug in destinations for the logged messages, filters, formatters.
10. Refactor:

    ```
    def get_similarities(user_doc_vec, i, filename):
        with open("./user_topics/cosine_similarities_clique" + str(i), 'a') as cosfile, open("./user_topics/hellinger_similarities_clique" + str(i), 'a') as helfile:
            for key in sorted(user_doc_vec):
                user = key
                vec_lda = user_doc_vec[key]
                dense_1 = gensim.matutils.sparse2full(vec_lda, lda_model.num_topics)
                del user_doc_vec[key]
                for key_2 in sorted(user_doc_vec):
                    dense_2 = gensim.matutils.sparse2full(user_doc_vec[key_2], lda_model.num_topics)
                    hel_sim = np.sqrt(0.5 * ((np.sqrt(dense_1) - np.sqrt(dense_2))**2).sum())
                    cosfile.write(str(user) + '\t' + str(gensim.matutils.cossim(vec_lda, user_doc_vec[key_2])) + '\t' + str(key_2) + '\n')
                    helfile.write(str(user) + '\t' + str(hel_sim) + '\t' + str(key_2) + '\n')
    ```

    - Don't use hard-coded paths. Put the paths into a constant/settings
    - Use `str.format` instead of `clique" + str(i)`
    - Use `for key, vec_lda in sorted(user_doc_vec.iteritems())` to iterate over the dict and get the key and the value in one step.
    - `vec_lda = user_doc_vec[key]; del user_doc_vec[key]` -> `vec_lda = user_doc_vec.pop(key)`. Anyway, the code smells as you are mutating the dict while walking over it. You also use `sorted` on each iteration step. Maybe you could use a list and do at the beginning `_user_doc_vec = sorted(user_doc_vec.iteritems())`, then you would sort only once and then in the second loop you would start with outer loop index -- no need to delete elements to exclude them from the inner loop.

Comment: About 5., I'd add that multiline strings aren't the same as comments. And you shouldn't use them as such in the first place.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger they look to me as a commented out code, not comments for the code.

Comment: Yes, I think so too. But even for commented out portions of code you should use comments and not multiline strings.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am mutating the dictionary as I'm iterating over it. I am doing this because I only want to perform a calculation for each user with all other users once. So, in the first iteration, if I perform a calculation for user 1 to 2 and 3, I don't need to perform a calculation for user 2 to 1 on the second iteration. I tried using a list before but the document vector needs to be associated with a user ID. I think I can do this with a list somehow but I would need to do it at the same time as I'm traversing the tweet directories and saving the documents.

Comment: I wasn't aware that multi line quotes were not comments. I always see people using them to comment. I'm laughing at myself right now about that tokenize function, it's not even necessary.

Comment: @KennethOrton Do not confuse yourself between multiline strings and [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) either. The former are random bits in the code, the latter is documentation.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I also know people using hanging multiline strings to comment parts of code. I think it's easier to add triple quotes on one line and another triple quotes an another line in editor which doesn't allow you to easily comment/uncomment blocks of code.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Oh, I see. I guess the issue is that I started learning at Codecademy, lol, and they specifically say multi-line comments can be made using triple quotes. They also teach you to use tons of <divs> in their html courses. Lesson learned, read a book instead.

Comment: @warvariuc until the day you need to "comment" a function with an associated docstring and your trick does not work anymore. Selecting the same function and hitting the del key is at least as fast in such editors. And if you ever need to retrieve that piece of code, ask your favorite version control system.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I don't use this trick, I just mentioned why others would use it. I agree that it's not a good idea to use triple quotes for commenting out code. Though I don't remember PEP-8 saying anything about this.